# Files under the "build" folder are generated and should not be edited

Tags: java, android, gradle, build

This morning I was coding an app following a tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iFdtSi1v1Vk/) and after adding

```
compile 'com.microsoft.projectoxford:emotion:1.0.355'
```

as stated in the tutorial to the build.gradle and then syncing the gradle, almost everything in my manifest turned red and I got the message stating "Files under the 'build' folder are generated and should not be edited." How do I fix this? I have tried everything in other stackoverflow forums related to this query to no avail. I really do not want to start over as I have put a large amount of effort into this app and would be devastated.

Screenshots -- https://i.stack.imgur.com/n0lID.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by removing the line of code that caused the issue and rebuilding the project, as well as syncing the gradle.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the error by cleaning the project. In the android studio, navigate to the Build, the click on CLean Project. It will solve.